# color picker not working when page is scrolled

Tags: jquery, css

I am at total loss here.  I am using Farbastic color picker and it works fine on all elements except for one. I have stripped the page down to just the one that does not work. 
It works fine in all browsers EXCEPT for firefox! 
When you click on the page a dialog comes up and you select "Change Background Color".  Then the color picker opens up.  If you are scrolled all the way up to the top of the page it works fine.  If you scroll down just a couple of inches (with the color picker still open), the color pickers stops working.
The sliders and input where you can enter the value will work at all times but the color wheel does not for some reason.

I've gone through every element thinking it was a z-index issue but found nothing.

The url for the test page is https://www.annearundelproperties.net/listing_flyers/create_flyer_test.php.  I would post the code but you can just view source on the link to get a better idea.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's ambiguity in firefox between the doc position and the viewport position - it's using the doc position when it should be using the viewport, thus the hit zone moves when you scroll. If you scroll just 50 px, you can still hit it off-center.

A quick google [turned up a fix](http://code.google.com/p/farbtastic/issues/detail?id=3) - let me know if it works for you.